# Check incrementation of adjacent spots in matrix, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I've been using CodeFights for a couple days (which I highly recommend as it's a great way to build on to your skills), and today I came across a challenge that I couldn't figure out for the life of me. I hate to give away solutions, but nothing I tried would work.

Generally, the challenge was this: Given any matrix of numbers, such as

```
[1,4,5,8]
[2,3,6,7]
```

as a parameter to a function, return true if, starting in the top-left corner, you could traverse all the numbers in the array, incrementing by one each time, by moving only to adjacent spots. So, I start at 1, 2 is adjacent so I can move there, 3 is adjacent to 2 so I can move there, and so on and so forth. If you can't get through the entire matrix then return false. It seems pretty simple until you get down to it. 
you must:

– Keep track and compare the number of items checked, against the number of items in the matrix.
– Somehow check each adjacent spot for the value of the current spot +1, and then make that the current spot. Then keep checking until you run out of numbers, otherwise return false.

I tried so many different ways of doing this, using 3 or 4 levels of nested `for` loops, and nothing I tried would work for all of the test cases. I probably wont ever see the problem again, but just for knowledge's sake, could anyone point me in the right direction? Namely just helping me to understand how to efficiently compare against adjacent spaces in a matrix (to maybe avoid giving away the answer for future CodeFighters)?

Just to clarify:

The function would be set up passing in a matrix:

```
function traverse(matrix) {

}
```

and something like this would return true:

```
[[ 1, 4, 5, 8]
 [ 2, 3, 6, 7]]
```

and something like this would return false:

```
[[ 1, 3, 5, 8]
 [ 2, 4, 9, 7]
 [10,12, 6,11]]
```

Any help just to understand where I may have gone wrong in my execution is greatly appreciated. (Btw I can't post exactly what I tried because I don't believe there's a way to get back to it on the website.)

Comment: Does the matrix always go from 1 to x hitting every integer in-between?

Comment: No it does not, it can start at any number, whichever is in the top left position. And that's another obstacle, you don't even know if each sequential number is in the matrix, without doing a check.

Comment: I don't know how to check matrix position off hand, but the rest shouldn't be too bad. Get value of top left. Increment by one. Check adjacent for that number. No match return false, match take that position and repeat the process. Keep a counter. If you do all the numbers return true.

Comment: Right, I thought it sounded that easy too, but it gets tricky when it comes to checking the adjacent values. When I tried it, I checked all 4 positions, but if there was nothing in that position it would give me an error, regardless of the fact that I ran a check first. For instance, the top left position is missing the left and top adjacent positions, trying to check them throws an error because, programmatically, you'd be passing in a negative position. Then, even if I could check the adjacent values, I couldn't return false right away because without somehow recording it, (continued)

Comment: there's no way to say that there's not a position I haven't checked yet. That's the logic I was having problems with.

Comment: I think you can prevent hitting errors with `if`s. `If outside bounds move to next check`. Figuring bounds might be tricky though.

Second problem, yes instead of just return false you would make a var like `match = false` set it to true if you get a hit, and use that in the fashion I described above.

Comment: I actually did try that, using a variable to store the true or false, I forgot about that, I apologize. But you're right about checking the points against the dimensions of the matrix. Before, all I had tried was setting the point as the parameter for my if statement, like you would do to see if most things evaluate to false or true, and that's what was giving me the errors. Thanks for your insight by the way. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing. Interesting problem. Sounds like you were pretty close.

Comment: It sure felt like it, and I really enjoyed trying to figure it out, it was just frustrating when nothing that I tried would work.